# How do i log all Exception in windows phone 8?

Tags: email, windows-phone-8

I craete one app using **EmailComposeTask** in windows phone8. It's Working fine. But at final of sent mail throw the exception. like the below image.

[image]

How can i solve the problem and why this problem occurred?.

Please Help Me. Thanks in Advance.

**Here My Code.**

```
    private void saveEmailAddressTask_Completed(object sender, TaskEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Email successfully Saved..");
        }
    }


    private void emailAddressChooserTask_Completed(object sender, EmailResult e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Selected email :" + e.Email);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }            

    private void mail_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {                
            EmailComposeTask Myemail_Composetask = new EmailComposeTask();
            Myemail_Composetask.Subject = "PhotoWrite Share";
            Myemail_Composetask.Body = "Hi, I am sharing my PhotoWrite Photo, Hope you Like it.";
            Myemail_Composetask.To = "";
            Myemail_Composetask.Show();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

On Windows Phone Emulator, an exception occurs when using the email compose task. Test the email compose task on a physical device.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394003(v=vs.105).aspx

You can also check the detail of the exception.

Comment: What's the detail of the Exception?